# How to communicate with a server using a TLS connection?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I am using python and SSL module to establish a TLS connection to a server. Then I would like to send some data to this server. To do this, I have a *CA-Certificate*, *Client Certificate*, and *Client Certificate Key* in a file called "cert.pem". Although my server code works fine, my client code fails to connect to the server. I just mimicked the [SSL module example](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) and I do not understand why it fails.

The **server code** that works fine:

```
import socket, ssl

cert_chain  = 'cert.pem'
host_addr   = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
host_port   = 10023

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_chain)
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind((host_addr, host_port))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
  print("Waiting for client")
  newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
  conn = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
  print("SSL established. Peer: {}".format(conn.getpeercert()))
  buf = b''  # Buffer to hold received client data
  try:
    while True:
      data = conn.recv(4096)
      if data:      # Client sent us data. Append to buffer
        buf += data
      else:         # No more data from client. Show buffer and close connection.
        print("Received:", buf)
        break
  finally:
    print("Closing connection")
    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
```

The **client code** that fails:

```
import socket, ssl

server_addr = '**.***.***.***'
server_port = 3335
cert_chain  = 'cert.pem'

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname=server_addr)
conn.connect((server_addr, server_port))

conn.send(b"Hello, world!")
conn.close()
```

When I run the client code, I get this error:

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)

However when I simply use [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278147/9696715), I am able to send data:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:10023
```

## Questions

- What is wrong with my client code?
- Why the `openssl s_client` command works but the python code does not?

I highly appreciate any suggestions to improve the code.

Comment: You try to connect to port `3335` but your server listens on `10023`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here:

a) According to your code, your server listens on port `10023`, but your client tries to connect to `3335`. But that is probably just a problem in the code you posted. If it was in the code you run, you would not have been able to establish a connection at all.

b) You get a `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` when the server certificate can not be verified by the client. For example, when you browse to `https://stackoverflow.com` you will see some sort of lock-symbol in your address bar, indicating, that your connection is secure. That is because the server supplies a certificate that is valid and trusted for the domain `stackoverflow.com`. In your case, your certificate is most probably neither valid, nor trusted.
For that to work, the certificate would need to have the IP address or hostname (whatever you supply as `server_hostname` in the `wrap_socket` method) as [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) and the certificate would need to be signed by a trusted CA. As you are probably using a self-signed certificate, this will not be the case, because your trust-store is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. When you issue your self-signed certificate, you can add the IP/hostname to SAN and CN and in your code, you can try to add the certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.
For development purposes, you can set `verify_mode` to `CERT_NONE` (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode)) which should solve all your problems for the moment. This should not be used in production, though.